# why do I get "getcwd() failed" when using crontab

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I am trying to use crontab on my ***ubntu 14.04*** system, however, when I executed `crontab -e` in home dir `~/`, the opened vim file ***/tmp/crontab.cndoND*** just can not be saved by `:wq`, I got `"crontab" E212: 无法打开并写入文件` error in vim, and got `sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory` error message in the terminal.

so what should I do to use crontab?

Comment: Translation: Unable to open and write to the file.

Comment: I understand the vim error message, however: the file is created in /tmp/, and authority mode for that folder is 777.

Comment: no, i wasn't providing a hint for you. i was providing a hint for the rest of the non-chinese-speaking members of this forum.

Comment: @tjeloep thans a lot!